# Check App update show image

Tags: xcode, ios7, notifications, uiimage

Please advice me something about this

[image: this]

i mean this one

[image: this]

Please advice the keyword name and Xcode have tool for this?
I'm use another way for this

example I'm add image to icon and i set image hidden if web service found new version will unhidden is works but Please advice if have any idea

*this image must in app not icon.//My English isn't well sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

That is the icon badge, you can control it by using the [`applicationIconBadgeNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationIconBadgeNumber) property in `UIApplication`

i.e.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
```

Comment: Thanks @L14M333 but i mean menu icon in app, the image is sample i need but i don't know how to explain //  in my app have another menu icon and check data from web service to set image like this